Computing eigendecomposition of a symmetric tridigonal matrix
I have a function $f(x)=1/x$ and I want to compute $f(X)$ where $X$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, First I tridiagonalize $X$ to $QTQ^T$ using lanczos algorithm and then I want to compute $f(T)=Uf(\Lambda)U^T$. Given that $T$ is symmetric and tridiagonal I'm looking for an algorithm to eigendecompose it in $O(n^2)$.
Is this possible at all? I mean I guess QR and LU factotizations have $O(n^3)$ complexity.
Is there a better algorithm?

can you specify $f$?

is T symmetric as well?

@GBmath yes, T is symmetric as well.

@GBmath And  yes $f=1/x$
